# Qt - Quick 2 App from new project (main.qml file not found)

Tags: c++, qt

I didn't change anything in default qt creator app, so all should be ok. I created new project and tried to compile and run. Compile process ok, but after run, main.qml not found, so i see just black window without any interface (there should be hello world text).

**qml1.pro**

```
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_01.source = qml/qml1
folder_01.target = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# If your application uses the Qt Mobility libraries, uncomment the following
# lines and add the respective components to the MOBILITY variable.
# CONFIG += mobility
# MOBILITY +=

# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp

# Installation path
# target.path =

# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/qml1/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Console output after app run from creator:**

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
file:///Users/Krab/projects/qtProjects/build-qml1-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_clang_64bit-Ladění/qml1.app/Contents/Resources/qml/qml1/main.qml: File not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I can build a application when the qml files are missing because they aren't processed or  anything. So everything seems fine to the compiler.

But I would advise you to look in the directory: `Users/Krab/projects/qtProjects/build-qml1-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_clang_64bit-Ladění/qml1.app/Contents/Resources/qml/qml1/`
To check if the QML files are located there.

Also where is you local qml file, is it in the project directory? Otherwise the builder doesn't have anything to export to the build directory.